# how can I put the class I am working on with the main in a single file?

Tags: java, class, public

I want to see my class and work on my main in parallel ,Eclipse suggests that I create a new class with its own file

I am new to java ,I don't know really how this works

```
class myClass {                                
}       

public class classMain {                                          
      public static void main(String [] args){                         
      }                                                                  
}
```

Comment: You should really do what Eclipse suggests and learn to split independent code into their own classes (also see [Single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). When you really want to see two classes at once, I would suggest to open both in parallel?

Comment: But they aren't really indepedant , the main executes the class that I am working on it

Comment: Independent in their responsibility. Main calls your other class, yes, but Main has a different purpose then the other class. Main is responsible in starting your application and the other class is responsible for something else, a calculation for example.

Comment: That was helpful thank you , I think I should make my class public so it can be defined in main ,is that right ?

Comment: When `myClass` were public, then you couldn't define it anywhere else than `myClass.java`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're new to Java, don't worry about splitting classes into separate files for now. I personally don't use Eclipse, but what you did is correct. You can add (above or below) a new class in the same file, using the same syntax!

```java
class OtherClass {
   // have your functions and fields here
}

public class classMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    //do stuff
    OtherClass other = new OtherClass();
    }
}
```

You can use, reference, instantiate, and do any number of things with multiple classes in the same file :)

Comment: That's what I did but when I called methods in main , Eclipse generates an error.It says that methods aren't defined in this field.Thankyou

Comment: @Ouiame Make sure you're instantiating the class as an object, otherwise you're going to have to make your methods `static` in the separate class. Other than that, I've never encountered that error, and a quick google search doesn't give any information on it. I'm sorry!